# Конструктор класса с шаблонным initializer_list

Tags: c++, ооп

Я решил написать свой собственный вектор (шаблон), и в качестве одного из вариантов его инициализации я хотел написать конструктор с шаблонным initializer_list, за что в ответ получил несколько ошибок, суть которых уловить мне не удалось

```
template <typename T>
class my_vector
{
public:

    my_vector(std::initializer_list<T> list)
    {
        std::initializer_list<T>::iterator iter = list.begin();
        arr = new T[list.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            arr[i] = *iter;
            iter++;
        }

        size = list.size();
    }

private:
    T* arr;
    int size;
};
```

В попытке инициализировать объект этого класса через braced-init-list, получаю следующие ошибки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: почему так происходит, и как решается такая проблема?

Comment: [Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо так:

```
my_vector(std::initializer_list<T> list)
{
    typename std::initializer_list<T>::iterator iter = list.begin();
    ...
```

Причина в том, что `std::initializer_list<T>::iterator` зависит от типа `T` и, теоретически, может оказаться не типом, а чем-то ещё. Для `std::initializer_list<T>::iterator` это явно не так, но компилятор всё равно требует внести ясность.

Comment: Большое спасибо, действительно работает! Однако, я все же не совсем понял суть происходящего. Не могли бы Вы подсказать, где можно ознакомиться с вопросами использования typename? @AVK

Comment: @Али Алисултанов На англоязычном сайте есть такой вопрос:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: Или просто `auto iter = list.begin();`.